# How to call Ubuntu bash from windows command prompt and redirect output to a file?

Tags: bash, shell, redirect, windows-10, command-prompt

In Windows 10 there is this Ubuntu Bash (Bash/WSL) and we can initiate it from cmd using `bash -c "command"`. This will initiate Ubuntu Bash and run the command in Linux environment. What I want is to redirect the out put of particular command into a text file.

**Ex:** `bash -c "command" >> file.txt` should have worked according to my knowledge but it didn't and I get `Error: 0x80070057` on the text file. 
[image]

Anyway, I solved the issue for the moment using the redirect of bash. I wrote a `.sh file` to use a redirect of Ubuntu Bash to write the content to a file.

**Ex:** `bash -c ./run_command.sh` on windows cmd, where `run_command.sh` contained `command >> file.txt`.

I think this is not the better solution for this. It should be able to do using windows cmd redirect.

Comment: `bash -c [COMMAND] >> [FILE_PATH]` Works perfectly for me. It opens without any errors. Are there any other details that might help explain your issue?

Comment: Updated the question added a screenshot.

Comment: what do you want to do? the `type` command looks not appropriate here.

Comment: `type` command is to see the content of the file. `file.txt` should contain the list of files in the dir if it worked.

Comment: Try opening the file in Notepad. It should definitely work there.

Comment: @ifconfig I tried that already. Lol :D